# Index columns order and Scan instead of seek

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

Please consider `Customer` table in `Northwind` Database:

I add an index on 3 columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_1] ON [dbo].[Customers]
    ([CompanyName] ASC, [City] ASC, [Country] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and I tested these queries:

```
1) SELECT CompanyName,city,country FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] where CompanyName='a' and city='b' and country='c'

2) SELECT CompanyName,city,country FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] where country='c' and CompanyName='a' and city='b'

3) SELECT CompanyName,city,country FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] where CompanyName='a' and country='c'

4) SELECT CompanyName,city,country FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] where CompanyName='a' and city='b'
```

all of above queries use `Index Seek`.

Is there these predicates **True**?

**A)** If my index has `N` columns then all permutation of these `N` columns with equality to their values are using `Index Seek` and so columns order in `Index` does not matters when all columns participate on `Where` clause.

**B)** If my index has `N` columns (for example: `Col1, Col2, Col3,...) then all these combinations in`Where`clause use`Index Seek`:

```
B-1) Col1, Col2,
B-2) Col1, Col2, Col3
B-3) Col1, Col3, Col4
B-4) Col1, Col4, Col7
```

So `Col1` is important to use `Index Seek`.

Please consider this query:

```
5) SELECT CompanyName,city,country, PostalCode FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] where CompanyName='a' and city='b' and country='c'
```

**C)** I added `PostalCode` in Select List and why does `Index Seek` convert to `Index Scan`? Why the `Seek`not converted to `Seek + Key Lookup`?

Comment: Can you supply an actual execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The column order does matter because the index key is constructed using the column ordering specified. So an index seek (rather than scan) could only be efficiently made if the `CompanyName` column is included in your predicate (as it is in all your `WHERE` clauses`). The order in which the columns are listed in the predicate does not matter - the query optimiser will ascertain whether the requisite columns are specified in order to perform a seek.

2) Again, `Col1` needs to be included as that is the first column specified for the index and thus forms the start of the index key.

3) Adding `PostalCode` means the index no longer covers all the columns needed in order to furnish the query. It is then up to the query optimiser to assess whether an index seek or an index scan is more efficient. This will depend on a number of factors, but an important one will be how many rows it estimates will be returned by the predicate and thus how many (expensive) key lookups it would have to perform relative to the expense of scanning the table (clustered index). It has clearly decided that in this case a scan of the clustered index is more efficient.